# Is it possible to use had to + past participle?

Tags: modal-verbs, past-participles, semi-modals

I always think that the proper use of this construction is, for example: 'After the death of her grandfather, she had to take over his duties on the farm'. 
This is a sentence from my paper, which returned corrected 'she had to took over'.

And I'm confused, because I was taught that the rule is: had to + infinitive. But on the other hand, my teacher is a native speaker and I found it hard to believe that he could make a mistake.

Is there some kind of rule that I don't know?

Comment: Your teacher made a mistake. To err is human.

Answer (score 14):

Your teacher made a mistake. "She had to took over" is incorrect grammar.

Answer (score 8):

In fact, "took" is the *past simple* of "take", and "taken" is the *past participle*. It is highly unlikely that a teacher should confuse "take" and "took". **I wonder whether your teacher merely crossed out only part** ("take") **of what she actually meant to cross out** ("had to take over") in order to have "after the death of her grandfather, *she took over* his duties on the farm."

"Had to" (and "have to" in any tense) **has to be followed** by infinitive.

> She had to take over.
>
> I had to do that.
>
> I have to go.
>
> I will have to wait.

Comment: But changing "had to take over" to "took over" changes the meaning.  The former implies some coercive influence that the latter does not.

Comment: @HotLicks It surely does, and I was just wondering whether the teacher meant to do that. The text may have been a "precis" based on a novel...who knows?

Answer (score 0):

Your teacher made a mistake, quite possible as we all are human-beings. Or maybe s/he just changed **had to take over into took over?** Anyway the answer **had to took over** is grammatically incorrect.